# A fact implied by Theorem 4.12 in Rudin's RCA

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, discrete-mathematics

[image]

I was reading the proof of Theorem 4.12 in Rudin's RCA. The theorem says there exists a unique $y\in H$ such that $Lx=(x,y),x\in H$, where L is a continuous linear functional, H is a Hilbert space. The contruction of $y$ is by defining $M=\{x: Lx=0\}$ and showing $M^{\bot}$ is nonempty. Then the unique $y$ is contructed by $y:=(\bar{Lz})z$, where $z\in M^{\bot},||z||=1$.

My question is, once we prove that $M^{\bot}$ is nonempty, for any $z' \in M^{\bot}$, we can always construct a $z$ such that $||z||=1$ and then the condition of the proof is satisfied and Eq. (3) in the proof can be defined. Does this mean for any $y,z\in M^{\bot}$ (without loss of generality, I assume ||y||=||z||=1), we always have $(\bar{Lz})z=(\bar{Ly})y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M^\perp$ is a one-dimensional, since as vector spaces, $M^\perp \cong H / M \cong H / \text{ker}(L)\cong \text{im}(L)$, and $\text{im}(L)$ is clearly one-dimensional.

So if $z_1, z_2$ are two elements in $M$ with unit norm, then $z_1 = \lambda z_2$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ such that $|\lambda| = 1$.

But then, $(L \bar z_1)z_1 = (\bar\lambda L\bar z_2) (\lambda z_2) = |\lambda|^2 (L\bar z_2)z_2 = (L\bar z_2)z_2$.